# Construction of two uncountable sequences which are "interleaved"

Tags: sequences-and-series, well-orders

I believe the answer to my following question is no, but some things about uncountable sets/sequences can be really counterintuitive so I wanted to double check:

Does there exist a pair of uncountable sequences $x_{\alpha}, y_{\alpha}$, indexed by $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and taking values in $[0,1]$, such that $x_{\alpha} < y_{\alpha}$ for all $\alpha$ and $y_{\alpha} < x_{\beta}$ for all $\alpha < \beta$?

Would appreciate any insights!

Comment: You should not call them "sequences"; what you have is two functions $x,y\colon\mathbb{R}\to[0,1]$ such that $x(\alpha)\lt y(\alpha)$ for all $\alpha$, and such that  $\alpha\lt\beta$ implies $y_{\alpha}\lt x_{\beta}$.

Comment: Your "uncountable sequences" are just functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $[0,1]$. Does that help you think about the problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, because this would give us an injection of $\mathbb R$ into $\mathbb Q$: for every $\alpha\in\mathbb R$, as $x_\alpha<y_\alpha$, find $q_\alpha\in\mathbb Q\cap(x_\alpha, y_\alpha)$ and notice that those $q_\alpha$ are all different: if $\alpha<\beta$ then $q_\alpha<y_\alpha<x_\beta<q_\beta$.

Comment: Nice! I was disappointed to see an answer popping just before mine but this is cool since the proofs are different!

Comment: Very elegant -- I like that this also immediately rules out any other uncountable "index set" which doesn't make the sequences into nice functions on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @psychicmachinist also note that we don't need choice axiom since we can explicitly find suitable $q_\alpha$'s

Answer (score 5):

Let us use another notation: $x(\alpha)$ and $y(\alpha)$. These are strictly increasing functions with image in $[0,1]$. Your assertion implies that each point of $\mathbb{R}$ is a discontinuity of $x$, but an increasing functions has at most a countable number of points of discontinuity, so this is absurd.

So you can't have this.

The same goes with image in $\mathbb{R}$